# BufferedReader.readLine() mangles binary

Tags: java, binary

For academic purposes, I am working on a small encryption-based application using java and java crypto. That said, I generally work in C or C++ (where this happens to be very easy) so I apologize if this is an obvious issue. So my issue comes when I want to decrypt information. The problem is not so much related to using crypto or anything, but, in fact, retrieving my initialization vector properly. For now I have a plaintext file with the following format new-line/colon delimited (yes, this is insecure but it's an academic exercise - obviously the key file would not be in plaintext in the real world)

```
password:salt:<IV>
```

Where `<IV>` is the initialization vector. I decided to write out the initialization vector directly in binary format. Now I here is where my problem begins. I can write out the data properly (verified using hexdump), but it does not seem that it is being properly read back into the program. For instance, consider a counter value of

```
00 18 C0 98 (decimal: 1622168)
```

This value is correctly written out. However, when I try to read it in, this value is all wrong. I suspect this is a result of `BufferedReader.readLine()`. I simply read this line and write it out to another file and this value is then changed to

```
BD EF BF BD (decimal: who cares, very wrong...)
```

But the ASCII values (password and salt) remain intact as well as the colon delimiters. The initialization vector binary is all the gets scrambled.

What I am trying to do is this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
String last  = null;
String parse = null;
while((last = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    parse = last;
}
reader.close();
int offset = // A few indexOf() statements to find the positon;
byte[] iv  = parse.substring(offset).getBytes();
```

At this point, `iv.length > 16` (using 128-bit AES) which is already wrong. So I am not entirely sure how I can accomplish this ASCII-binary mix (perhaps it is bad design to begin with). Part of my issue is that `char != byte` in Java and I cannot simply read everything in as byte's if I want to read a full line (using `readLine()` anyway). But is there anyway to get around this issue? Since I want the full line, but I also want to extract binary from this line.

Additionally, I have also tried a direct conversion

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; ++i)
  iv[i] = (byte)parse.charAt(offset + i);
```

But this does not work either. The other code (`getBytes()`-based) was working on my personal machine with `java version "1.6.0_37"`, but the deployment environment is using `java version "1.6.0_33"` where this is failing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't use Readers on binary data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is a line of binary data? How do you know which `0x0A` is data and which is a newline?

The point is [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) is meant for reading *text*, not arbitrary data! It will treat all of your data as text. It will also attempt to convert your binary to text using some encoding, which will of course mangle your data.

A better method would be to either:

- Not write any of your data as binary, and rely on newlines or some other delimiter. (e.g. keep using `BufferedReader.readLine()`)
- Write all of your data as binary, and either make each record in your file of a fixed length, or come up with some more complicated delimiter scheme. (e.g. just use `FileInputStream.read(byte[])`)

Comment: I was reading the note on `DataInputStream.readLine()` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()) and why it was deprecated and was under the impression that `BufferedReader.readLine()` would not mangle bytes like this.

Comment: The issue in both cases is that the reader tries to convert raw bytes to characters (text), and your data is not text! Or not entirely text anyways.

Comment: Bah - makes sense, I suppose. Thanks for your help - not used to having such stipulations on how to interpret data (although you bring up a good point - that said, my data does not contain any crlf binary codes)!

Comment: I bet it does contain non-ASCII characters though (e.g. bytes > 127). It will try to convert those into text based on the default encoding, and most likely fail (since the data is more-or-less random). Cheers and good luck on the rest of your project.